# Postgresql проблема с кодировкой

Tags: windows, postgresql, кодировка

Установил PostgreSQL 9.4, PgAdmin III 1.20 Version. Создал Базы, pgadmin по умолчанию создаёт базы с кодировкам `utf-8`. Когда к таблицу в базе добавляем русский символы через `.sql` файл, в базе все русский символы выходит кривое.
[image: pgadmin, postgresql проблема с кодировкой]

хотел исправить этот проблему, поискал google и нашел это: [PostgreSQL - Кириллица в psql под Windows](http://www.iu5bmstu.ru/index.php/PostgreSQL_-_%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%B2_psql_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4_Windows)

Открыл `cmd` и хотел написать советы из найденный сайта, но `cmd.exe` тоже такая проблема:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не знаю как исправить этот проблему. Помогите пожалуйста решит это проблему. Тип операционная систему: Windows 7 Корпоративная (*Service Pack 1*)

Comment: Файл .sql UTF-8? Записываете его в базу чем? А cmd вообще работает в cp866. И chcp 1251 надо запускать в приглашении cmd (>), а не pgsql (#). Но это в любом случае не поможет, если файл utf.

Comment: проверял файл на notepad++ , там кодировки стоит utf-8 (без BOM)

Comment: Ну так загрузите его через тот же admin. Admin открывает sql в кодировке utf-8, там если что параметр есть в настройках.

Comment: .sql файлы выполняется через java spring framework. При первое запуске приложению, создает таблицы и заполняет таблицы через эти sql файлом

Comment: Фреймвёрк их сам загружает? Или файл своей функцией читаете? В любом случае надо указать кодировку файла или фрейвёрку или при открытии файла. По умолчанию будет наверняка win1251.